# Grails 3 integration with IDEA 15. Error exists in the bytecode

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

Guys i am trying to run my Hello World application built on Grails 3. I use Intellij IDEA as IDE and when i try to create domain class i get next error.

```
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/grails/cli/interactive/completers/AllClassCompleter.<init>()V @123: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b800 144c 04bd 0016 5903 2b12 1732 2b12
    0000010: 1832 2b12 1932 121b 2b12 1c32 121e b900
    0000020: 2402 0012 26b9 002a 0400 b900 2d02 00bb
    0000030: 002f 5912 0212 02b7 0032 b900 3503 0012
    0000040: 37b8 003d c000 3712 37b8 0041 5359 10ff
    0000050: 1204 b800 452a 5fab 0000 003f 0000 0002
    0000060: 1374 8337 0000 0019 4ad1 f42c 0000 002a
    0000070: 5f5a 0312 37b8 004b c000 37b7 004e a700
    0000080: 225f 5a59 0332 121b b800 51c0 001b 5f57
    0000090: b700 54a7 000d bb00 5659 1258 b700 5bbf
    00000a0: 572a b600 5f4d 2c2a 5fb5 0061 2c57 b1  
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@112,{UninitializedThis,Object[#101]},{Object[#103],UninitializedThis})
    full_frame(@129,{UninitializedThis,Object[#101]},{Object[#103],UninitializedThis})
    full_frame(@150,{UninitializedThis,Object[#101]},{Object[#103],UninitializedThis})
    full_frame(@160,{Object[#2],Object[#101]},{Object[#103]})
 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Does anybody know how to fix it in MAC OS?

Also, i haven't done anything with my project. Just generated project from scratch  using IDEA -> New Project -> Grails.

I use Java 8

Comment: Might be a JVM bug, what is your exact JVM version?

Comment: I see the same thing, for ever Grails command using 3.1.1.  Java -version: java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

Try to update JDK.
It helped me (1.8.0_20 to 1.8.0_96 in my case).